# dynamically index between columns in R

Tags: r, indexing

This should be straightforward but I can't find an answer to my question. I want to index a subset of columns in my data frame e.g:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'c1', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'h1'),
                  var2 = c(7, 9, 2, 4, 3, 6, 8, 2, 1, 2),
                  var3 = c(21, 50, 40, 30, 29, 45, 33, 51, 70, 46),
                  var4 = c(1, 5, 2, 4, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 1))

df1[c(2:4)]

   var2 var3 var4
1     7   21    1
2     9   50    5
3     2   40    2
4     4   30    4
5     3   29    1
6     6   45    2
7     8   33    3
8     2   51    3
9     1   70    5
10    2   46    1
```

But by name, where the column name may change. e.g:

```
df1[c(colname1:colname2)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:` doesn't work with character column names and `[`. But you can use `base::subset` using the column names directly, or `dplyr::select` directly or programmatically:

```
subset(df1, select = var2:var4)

library(dplyr)
select(df1, var2:var4)

## programmatically
x1 = "var2"
x2 = "var4"
select(df1, !!x1 : !!x2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I often use `grep` with `names(the_data)` to accomplish similar goals. For instance, with your original data:

```
df1[grep("var", names(df1))]

#    var2 var3 var4
# 1     7   21    1
# 2     9   50    5
# 3     2   40    2
# ....
```

If you change the names of certain columns (here, columns 2 and 3):

```
names(df1)[2:3] <- c("col1", "col2")

df1[grep("col", names(df1))]

#    col1 col2
# 1     7   21
# 2     9   50
# 3     2   40
# ....
```

If you want to use `:` to index between columns with specific names or without common patterns:

```
names(df1) <- c("id", "start_col", "abc", "end_col")

df1[grep("^start_col$", names(df1)):grep("^end_col$", names(df1))]

#    start_col abc end_col
# 1          7  21       1
# 2          9  50       5
# 3          2  40       2
# ...
```

Comment: I need to use : to index between columns and the real df has a lot of columns, so it doesn't really work to define them all in names(df1) <-

Comment: @Loz I'm a bit confused. I simply changed the name to show examples of how this approach could work. You dont need to change the names in your real dataset. You could replace the regex in the last option with whatever your start and end column names are.